# Python web scraping with BS using correct url?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Beginner at this. I have this code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logurl = "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login"
posturl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(logurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    values = {
        'p_flow_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_id']")['value'],
        'p_flow_step_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_step_id']")['value'],
        'p_instance': soup.select_one("[name='p_instance']")['value'],
        'p_page_submission_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_submission_id']")['value'],
        'p_request': 'LOGIN',
        'p_arg_names': soup.select_one("[name='p_arg_names']")['value'],
        'p_t01': 'username',
        'p_arg_names': soup.select_one("[name='p_arg_names']")['value'],
        'p_t02': 'password',
        'p_md5_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_md5_checksum']")['value'],
        'p_page_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_checksum']")['value']
    }

    r = s.post(posturl, data=values)
    print r.content
```

`logurl` = url where login takes place
`posturl` = form action url where login data is posted.

However, when I try to use this, the content is returning the 'password incorrect` page, even though it has been entered correctly.

When I do manually login correctly to see the correct url page with the data I need, I notice that the url is actually the location url listed below (from chrome tools 'network', see image below), that includes the `flow_id` and `instance` values from the code:

`Location: https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=1500:1:9004571425464`

`Request URL: https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept`

`Referer: https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login`

[image]

Should I not be trying to 'post' to this url, instead of the request url?

Edit 1 :

```
  import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logurl = "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login"
posturl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {
            "Host": "login.flash.co.za",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Origin": "https://login.flash.co.za",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Referer": "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    }
    res = s.get(logurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

    values = {
        'p_flow_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_id']")['value'],
        'p_flow_step_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_step_id']")['value'],
        'p_instance': soup.select_one("[name='p_instance']")['value'],
        'p_page_submission_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_submission_id']")['value'],
        'p_request': 'LOGIN',
        'p_arg_names': soup.select_one("[name='p_arg_names']")['value'],
        'p_t01': 'solar',
        'p_arg_names': soup.select_one("[name='p_arg_names']")['value'],
        'p_t02': 'password',
        'p_md5_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_md5_checksum']")['value'],
        'p_page_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_checksum']")['value']
    }

    r = s.post(posturl, data=values)
    print r.content
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the referer before the post? s.headers.update({'referer': logurl})

Comment: If you could add this to my code in the correct place I could try it? Or would `Edit 1` do the same thing?

Comment: Edit 1 would be fine, putting it in all the headers would't hurt, but you only may have needed it, if it was the thing that was breaking it, before the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same value for "p_arg_names" twice. It should be two different values. Try passing it in as a list like this (completely untested code as I don't have a user-name or password.):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logurl = "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login"
posturl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(logurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

    arg_names =[]
    for name in  soup.select("[name='p_arg_names']"):
        arg_names.append(name['value'])

    values = {
        'p_flow_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_id']")['value'],
        'p_flow_step_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_step_id']")['value'],
        'p_instance': soup.select_one("[name='p_instance']")['value'],
        'p_page_submission_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_submission_id']")['value'],
        'p_request': 'LOGIN',
        'p_t01': 'username',
        'p_arg_names': arg_names,
        'p_t02': 'password',
        'p_md5_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_md5_checksum']")['value'],
        'p_page_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_checksum']")['value']
    }
    s.headers.update({'Referer': logurl})
    r = s.post(posturl, data=values)
    print (r.content)
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan-Dev would you agree with the comments on the next part of my struggle that it would be better to do all of this with selenium? `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912466/python-web-scraping-with-requests-after-login`

Comment: That depends. If you can scrape the URLs you want without Selenium then that would be better. Selenium is a bit clunky and overkill for a lot of situations. If you can extract the links you need without it then that would be easier and better. Without a login to the site I'm afraid you are not going to get much help either way.

Comment: Would you be able to help if I gave logon? There's not much one can do ( I hope), besides look at a few lines of data once logged in.

Comment: There is another way to go. You can put the contents displayed by "print (r.content)" into https://pastebin.com/ and go from there. First thing is to extract the URL for "statement in the first row" then make a request to that then make a POST request to simulate clicking the Run Statement button

Comment: when you say url for 'statement in the first row', do you mean the url of that page (after login), or the href for the 'statement' button?

Comment: the href for the 'statement' button

Answer (score 0):

Intercepted the request in `Fiddler`

The URL your posting to is correct just set the following headers and try logging in again

```
headers = {
            "Host": "login.flash.co.za",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "Origin": "https://login.flash.co.za",
            "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT x.y; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0",
            "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Referer": "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
}
```

Comment: See `Edit 1`. Is this how you meant it to be changed? I'm still getting the 'password incorrect' message returned...