# Python web scraping with requests - after login

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a python requests/beatiful soup code  below which enables me to login to a url successfully. However, after logon, to get the data I need would normally have to manually have to:

1) click on 'statement' in the first row:

[image]

2) Select dates, click 'run statement':

[image]

3) view data:

[image]

This is the code that I have used to logon to get to step 1 above:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

logurl = "https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f?p=pwfone:login"
posturl = 'https://login.flash.co.za/apex/wwv_flow.accept'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
    res = s.get(logurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

    arg_names =[]
    for name in  soup.select("[name='p_arg_names']"):
        arg_names.append(name['value'])

    values = {
        'p_flow_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_id']")['value'],
        'p_flow_step_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_flow_step_id']")['value'],
        'p_instance': soup.select_one("[name='p_instance']")['value'],
        'p_page_submission_id': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_submission_id']")['value'],
        'p_request': 'LOGIN',
        'p_t01': 'solar',
        'p_arg_names': arg_names,
        'p_t02': 'password',
        'p_md5_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_md5_checksum']")['value'],
        'p_page_checksum': soup.select_one("[name='p_page_checksum']")['value']
    }
    s.headers.update({'Referer': logurl})
    r = s.post(posturl, data=values)
    print (r.content)
```

My question is, (beginner speaking), how could I skip steps 1 and 2 and simply do another headers update and post using the final URL using selected dates as form entries (headers and form info below)? (The `referral header` is step 2 above):

[image]
]

Edit 1: network request from csv file download:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have recommended, Selenium is a good tool for this sort of task. However, I'd try to suggest a way to use `requests` for this purpose as that's what you asked for in the question.

The success of this approach would really depend on how the webpage is built and how data files are made available (if "Save as CSV" in the view data is what you're targeting).

If the login mechanism is cookie-based, you can use [Sessions](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) and [Cookies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies) in requests. When you submit a login form, a cookie is returned in the response headers. You add the cookie to  request headers in any subsequent page requests to make your login stick.

Also, you should inspect the network request for "Save as CSV" action in the Developer Tools network pane. If you can see a structure to the request, you may be able to make a direct request within your authenticated session, and use a statement identifier and dates as the payload to get your results.

Comment: Thanks. I added the csv file download network inspection. Think its doable to do a direct request?

Comment: I think it's doable - use the sessions and cookies, and then use BeautifulSoup to get the link for "Save as CSV" and do a GET request to `https://login.flash.co.za/apex/f` with the payload.

Comment: Thanks. If there is anyway you could add to my script, even with a basic framework of what you mean above (even just added comments for what goes where), it would help me immensely.

Answer (score 0):

Use selenium webdriver, it has a lot of good functions to handle web services.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is gonna be your best bet for automated browser interactions. It can be used not only to scrape data from websites but also to interact with different forms and such. I highly recommended it as I have used it quite a bit in the past.
If you already have pip and python installed go ahead and type

> pip install selenium

That will install selenium but you also need to install either geckodriver (for Firefox) or chromedriver (for chrome)
Then you should be up and running!