# How to submit a page in Oracle Apex using curl

Tags: oracle, curl, post, oracle-apex

I have a login page in an Oracle Apex application that works fine with a normal web browser like chrome. However when i try to perform the same operation using CURL (command-line browser), a HTTP 404 error is returned:

**Request**:

`curl -i -d "P9999_USERNAME=MOIZ&P9999_PASSWORD=xxxx" -X POST http://localhost:8080/apex/f?p=101:9999:0:`

**Response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
Server: Oracle XML DB/Oracle Database
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>404 Not found</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY><H1>Not found</H1>
The requested URL /apex/f was not found on this server</BODY></HTML>
```

Using a normal browser, there are two sever request: one GET and one POST. However when using curl i am just making a single POST request.

- Is that difference the cause of problem?
- Is it possible to POST apex page without calling GET?
- If yes then whether this solution will also work for file uploads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the post [Python web scraping with BS using correct url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50898876/python-web-scraping-with-bs-using-correct-url) I was able to get answer to my above questions. [although this post uses python's **requests** and **BeautifulSoup** libraries for demonstration purpose, I think with some shell/windows scripting it may also be achievable with curl too]

**Is that difference the cause of problem?**

For POST request in APEX, we need to first perform a GET request as APEX expects the following hidden items to be sent as a payload of POST request

```
    p_flow_id                 # application id
    p_flow_step_id            # page id 
    p_instance                # session id
    p_page_submission_id      # page submission id
    p_request                 # request 
    p_md5_checksum            # md5 checksum
    p_page_checksum           # page checksum  
    p_arg_names               # list of arguments
```

In addition, you may also need to add your page specific input items. For example,

```
    p_t01   # username
    p_t02   # password
```

**Is it possible to POST apex page without calling GET?**

For reasons mentioned in above answer, GET request will be required before POST request can be performed.